# sas pattern matching with square brackets evaluation

Tags: regex, sas

I have the following SAS code that checks for patterns and flags any error.

I'm sure that it checks for a pattern in field1, but I'm not sure how two square brackets [] are evaluated.

I need to check for invalid values in field1.

sas code:

```
if prxmatch('/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/', strip(&vfiel1)) = 0 then do;
     put "Error is field1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will check for valid-looking SAS name. Specifically, it must start (`^`) with a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`) followed by 0 or more (`*`) letters, numbers, and/or underscores (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) before the end (`$`).

A better SAS name check would be something along the lines of this:

- Libnames: `^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,7}$`
- Dataset & variable names: `^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,31}$`

Note these allow names to start with an underscore and have max lengths of 8 and 32 characters.

[Here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000998953.htm) is a page on Names in the SAS Language.